# Is there a standard XML spreadsheet code?

Tags: xml, excel, spreadsheet, border

I want to create an 'universal' XML spreadsheet compatible document... Something compatible both with Microsoft Excel and especially with the open source alternatives (OpenOffice Calc, Gnumeric, ..).

There's an issue I encounter when I try to border some cells. This is how you do it in Excel:

```
  <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="6"/>

  <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="6"/>
</Borders>
```

And here's a Gnumeric example:

```
<gnm:StyleBorder>
  <gnm:Bottom Style="1" Color="0:0:0"/>
  <gnm:Left Style="1" Color="0:0:0"/>
</gnm:StyleBorder>
```

Is there a standard approach?

Answer (score 1):

Each spreadsheet will have its own format and they are not compatible with each other.

Until all spreadsheet vendors commit to support a standard format this will not be possible.

Your best option is to develop [XSL](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) transformations that can convert one type of XML to another.